# D3 Force layout DIV vs SVG

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to modify the d3 force layout from SVG to DIV's. It seems the collision detection doesnt work as well with DIV's. You can see the working examples below.

(Another quick question, anyone know why css transform:translate isnt used for hardware acceleration)

DIV Version

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
  body,
  html {
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%
  }
  .divs div {
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: red;
    position: absolute;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.js"></script>

  <script>
    var width = $('body').width(),
      height = $('body').height(),
      padding = 10, // separation between nodes
      maxRadius = 30;

    var n = 20, // total number of nodes
      m = 1; // number of distinct clusters

    var color = d3.scale.category10()
      .domain(d3.range(m));

    var xPos = d3.scale.ordinal()
      .domain(d3.range(m))
      .rangePoints([width, width], 1);

    var x =
      d3.scale.linear()
      .domain([0, width])
      .range([0, width]);

    var y =
      d3.scale.linear()
      .domain([0, height])
      .range([0, height]);

    var nodes = d3.range(n).map(function() {
      var i = Math.floor(Math.random() * m),
        v = (i + 1) / m * -Math.log(Math.random());
      return {
        radius: Math.random() * maxRadius + 20,
        color: color(i),
        cx: xPos(i),
        cy: height
      };
    });

    var force = d3.layout.force()
      .nodes(nodes)
      .size([width, height])
      .gravity(0)
      .charge(0)
      .on("tick", tick)
      .start();

    var $body = d3.select("body")
      .append("div").attr('class', 'divs')
      .attr('style', function(d) {
        return 'width: ' + width + 'px; height: ' + height + 'px;';
      });

    var $div = $body.selectAll("div")
      .data(nodes)
      .enter()
      .append("div")
      .attr('style', function(d) {
        return 'width: ' + (d.radius * 2) + 'px; height: ' + (d.radius * 2) + 'px; margin-left: -' + d.radius + 'px; margin-top: -' + d.radius + 'px;';
      })
      .call(force.drag);

    function tick(e) {
      $div
        .each(gravity(.2 * e.alpha))
        .each(collide(.5))
        .style('left', function(d) {
          return x(Math.max(d.radius, Math.min(width - d.radius, d.x))) + 'px';
        })
        .style('top', function(d) {
          return y(Math.max(d.radius, Math.min(height - d.radius, d.y))) + 'px';
        });
    }

     // Move nodes toward cluster focus.
    function gravity(alpha) {
      return function(d) {
        d.y += (d.cy - d.y) * alpha;
        d.x += (d.cx - d.x) * alpha;
      };
    }

     // Resolve collisions between nodes.
    function collide(alpha) {
      var quadtree = d3.geom.quadtree(nodes);
      return function(d) {
        var r = d.radius + maxRadius + padding,
          nx1 = d.x - r,
          nx2 = d.x + r,
          ny1 = d.y - r,
          ny2 = d.y + r;
        quadtree.visit(function(quad, x1, y1, x2, y2) {
          if (quad.point && (quad.point !== d)) {
            var x = d.x - quad.point.x,
              y = d.y - quad.point.y,
              l = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y),
              r = d.radius + quad.point.radius + (d.color !== quad.point.color) * padding;
            if (l < r) {
              l = (l - r) / l * alpha;
              d.x -= x *= l;
              d.y -= y *= l;
              quad.point.x += x;
              quad.point.y += y;
            }
          }
          return x1 > nx2 || x2 < nx1 || y1 > ny2 || y2 < ny1;
        });
      };
    }
  </script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
body, html { margin: 0;width: 100%; height: 100%}
circle {
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.js"></script>

<script>

var width = $('body').width(),
    height = $('body').height(),
    padding = 10, // separation between nodes
    maxRadius = 40;

var n = 10, // total number of nodes
    m = 1; // number of distinct clusters

var color = d3.scale.category10()
    .domain(d3.range(m));

var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(d3.range(m))
    .rangePoints([width - 200, width], 1);

var nodes = d3.range(n).map(function() {
  var i = Math.floor(Math.random() * m),
      v = (i + 1) / m * -Math.log(Math.random());
  return {
    radius: Math.random() * maxRadius + 30,
    color: color(i),
    cx: x(i),
    cy: height
  };
});

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .nodes(nodes)
    .size([width, height])
    .gravity(0)
    .charge(0)
    .on("tick", tick)
    .start();

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var circle = svg.selectAll("circle")
    .data(nodes)
  .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("r", function(d) { return d.radius; })
    .style("fill", function(d) { return d.color; })
    .call(force.drag);

function tick(e) {
  circle
      .each(gravity(.2 * e.alpha))
      .each(collide(.5))
      //.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
      //.attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });

      .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x = Math.max(d.radius, Math.min(width - d.radius, d.x)); })
      .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y = Math.max(d.radius, Math.min(height - d.radius, d.y)); });

}

// Move nodes toward cluster focus.
function gravity(alpha) {
  return function(d) {
    d.y += (d.cy - d.y) * alpha;
    d.x += (d.cx - d.x) * alpha;
  };
}

// Resolve collisions between nodes.
function collide(alpha) {
  var quadtree = d3.geom.quadtree(nodes);
  return function(d) {
    var r = d.radius + maxRadius + padding,
        nx1 = d.x - r,
        nx2 = d.x + r,
        ny1 = d.y - r,
        ny2 = d.y + r;
    quadtree.visit(function(quad, x1, y1, x2, y2) {
      if (quad.point && (quad.point !== d)) {
        var x = d.x - quad.point.x,
            y = d.y - quad.point.y,
            l = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y),
            r = d.radius + quad.point.radius + (d.color !== quad.point.color) * padding;
        if (l < r) {
          l = (l - r) / l * alpha;
          d.x -= x *= l;
          d.y -= y *= l;
          quad.point.x += x;
          quad.point.y += y;
        }
      }
      return x1 > nx2 || x2 < nx1 || y1 > ny2 || y2 < ny1;
    });
  };
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is you are not updating the d.x and d.y in the tick so the layout will never come to know if they are colliding or not.

```
.style('left', function(d) {
  //update the d.x
  d.x = x(Math.max(d.radius, Math.min(width - d.radius, d.x)))
  return d.x  + 'px';
})
.style('top', function(d) {
  //update the d.y
  d.y=y(Math.max(d.radius, Math.min(height - d.radius, d.y)));
  return d.y + "px"
});
```

Working code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
  body,
  html {
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%
  }
  .divs div {
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: red;
    position: absolute;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.js"></script>

  <script>
    var width = $('body').width(),
      height = $('body').height(),
      padding = 10, // separation between nodes
      maxRadius = 30;

    var n = 20, // total number of nodes
      m = 1; // number of distinct clusters

    var color = d3.scale.category10()
      .domain(d3.range(m));

    var xPos = d3.scale.ordinal()
      .domain(d3.range(m))
      .rangePoints([width, width], 1);

    var x =
      d3.scale.linear()
      .domain([0, width])
      .range([0, width]);

    var y =
      d3.scale.linear()
      .domain([0, height])
      .range([0, height]);

    var nodes = d3.range(n).map(function() {
      var i = Math.floor(Math.random() * m),
        v = (i + 1) / m * -Math.log(Math.random());
      return {
        radius: Math.random() * maxRadius + 20,
        color: color(i),
        cx: xPos(i),
        cy: height
      };
    });

    var force = d3.layout.force()
      .nodes(nodes)
      .size([width, height])
      .gravity(0)
      .charge(0)
      .on("tick", tick)
      .start();

    var $body = d3.select("body")
      .append("div").attr('class', 'divs')
      .attr('style', function(d) {
        return 'width: ' + width + 'px; height: ' + height + 'px;';
      });

    var $div = $body.selectAll("div")
      .data(nodes)
      .enter()
      .append("div")
      .attr('style', function(d) {
        return 'width: ' + (d.radius * 2) + 'px; height: ' + (d.radius * 2) + 'px; margin-left: -' + d.radius + 'px; margin-top: -' + d.radius + 'px;';
      })
      .call(force.drag);

    function tick(e) {
  $div
    .each(gravity(.2 * e.alpha))
    .each(collide(.5))
    .style('left', function(d) {
      d.x = x(Math.max(d.radius, Math.min(width - d.radius, d.x)))
      return d.x  + 'px';
    })
    .style('top', function(d) {
      d.y=y(Math.max(d.radius, Math.min(height - d.radius, d.y)));
      return d.y + "px"
    });
    }

     // Move nodes toward cluster focus.
    function gravity(alpha) {
      return function(d) {
        d.y += (d.cy - d.y) * alpha;
        d.x += (d.cx - d.x) * alpha;
      };
    }

     // Resolve collisions between nodes.
    function collide(alpha) {
      var quadtree = d3.geom.quadtree(nodes);
      return function(d) {
        var r = d.radius + maxRadius + padding,
          nx1 = d.x - r,
          nx2 = d.x + r,
          ny1 = d.y - r,
          ny2 = d.y + r;
        quadtree.visit(function(quad, x1, y1, x2, y2) {
          if (quad.point && (quad.point !== d)) {
            var x = d.x - quad.point.x,
              y = d.y - quad.point.y,
              l = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y),
              r = d.radius + quad.point.radius + (d.color !== quad.point.color) * padding;
            if (l < r) {
              l = (l - r) / l * alpha;
              d.x -= x *= l;
              d.y -= y *= l;
              quad.point.x += x;
              quad.point.y += y;
            }
          }
          return x1 > nx2 || x2 < nx1 || y1 > ny2 || y2 < ny1;
        });
      };
    }
  </script>
```

Hope this helps!